# My script to stop restart my apache and mysql service doesn't work when started by a cron job

Tags: shell

I created the following script to stop apache and mysql and then restart them. When started manually it works fine, however when executed from a daily cron job I can see the logs, but the database is NOT restarted. Any idea why?

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

service apache2 stop
echo $(date ) "Apache stopped"
sleep  15
service mysql stop
echo $(date ) "Mysql stopped"
sleep 60
service mysql start
echo $(date ) "Mysql started"
sleep 5
service apache2 start
echo $(date ) "Apache started"
```

Comment: Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: There's no error in the logs, but it looks like the 'service ...' commands are skipped. There's no delay in executing them from a cron job and I can confirm that the services are not restarted. However executing the job manually works fine

Comment: I was thinking if this is something related to the bash profile loading. When running manually bash profile gets loaded by itself but in cron you need to load it while running the script. May be you can check that.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about this? I can still see every output of the echo commands when the job is started by the cron table

Comment: If stopping of `mysql` didn't work, kill the process. Start it again.

Comment: @sungtm I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment. I don't want to kill the process and corrupt my database. I want to be able to restart it from a CRON job and it looks like those commands are somehow ignored for some reasons

Comment: Try changing `service mysql` with `/etc/init.d/mysql ` and also for `apache2`. Also try with `#!/bin/bash` shebang.

Comment: @sungtm Thanks a lot. Please add this as an answer so I can accept your solution

Comment: @user1026605, welcome. It's glad to know that your problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `service mysql` with `/etc/init.d/mysql`.

Similarly, try using `/etc/init.d/apache2` instead of `service apache2`.

Also, try with `#!/bin/bash` shebang.